# How to get a time difference between two time columns for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have two tables I am trying to get a difference from in SQL. Table A has a time in the following format: 07:40:06,
08:33:34,
13:42:09,

Table B is in the same format. I want to return in an actual time for example 7:40:00 in A and 7:50:00 in B result in new column 00:10:00.

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Datediff only returns mins or hours or miliseconds etc. I need it in the format I posted above]

Comment: *"and `DATEADD`*" @Trand17. Hint: If the number seconds between 2 times is 160 seconds, and you add that that many seconds to midnight, what value do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I admit that this is sort of cheesy, but appears to work.  You could use a constant date, and add the times to that as strings.  Then subtract and format however you like.  For example: HH:mm:ss.  This will give the result of 00:10:00

```
DECLARE @contstantDate DATETIME = DATEFROMPARTS(1900,1,1)
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = @contstantDate + '7:40:00'
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = @contstantDate + '7:50:00'


SELECT FORMAT(@date2-@date1, 'HH:mm:ss')
```